# How to import **/* glob scss in Rails with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm using a Rails 5.2 app and have an `application.scss` file filled with individual imports

```
@import '../stylesheets/pages/home';
@import '../stylesheets/pages/product_details';
@import '../stylesheets/pages/cart';
@import '../stylesheets/pages/downloads';
```

This is laborious and error prone so I'd prefer to use globbing

```
@import '../stylesheets/components/*';
```

However, this fails. When I run `bin/webpack` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/webpacker/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--7-3!./app/webpacker/stylesheets/application.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import '../stylesheets/components/*';
^
File to import not found or unreadable: ../stylesheets/components/*.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I ended up giving up and just having 25 lines of imports. Perhaps one way to do this automatically would be to change the `application.scss` file to `application.scss.erb` and then then use ruby to loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution either and also went with multiple lines of imports... Seems there is no other way then to embrace "best practices"... welp

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by ErvalhouS, you have to use an importer that will enable this functionality.

Install the importer:

```
yarn add node-sass-glob-importer
```

Then configure the sass loader (installed by default with Webpacker) to use this when parsing css files:

```
const globCssImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

environment.loaders.get('sass')
  .use
  .find(item => item.loader === 'sass-loader')
  .options
  .sassOptions = {importer: globCssImporter()};
```

Then you can import directories in your application.scss file

```
@import '../stylesheets/components/**/*.scss';
```

If there are issues with load ordering, then loading the required files first in the correct ordering within application.scss should resolve that

```
@import '../stylesheets/components/defaults.scss'
@import '../stylesheets/components/**/*.scss';
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using [some plugin to enable glob importing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-glob-importer), SASS or SCSS does not support glob importing.

In SASS or SCSS import order matters, you need to be **explicit** about it or end up with undefined variables or mixins.

There is no built-in feature to do what you want. You either transform your file into `.erb` and loop or do some JS magic to import all files.